# Swapping the row data and column data in react aggrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Using react ag-grid for displaying the data in the table format.

Trying to swap the row and column data in the below but didn't work.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';

import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';

const App = () => {
   const [rowData] = useState([
      {make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000},
      {make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000},
      {make: "Porsche", model: "Boxster", price: 72000}
   ]);

const [columnDefs] = useState([
    { field: 'make' },
    { field: 'model' },
    { field: 'price' }
]);

return (
    <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{height: 400, width: 600}}>
        <AgGridReact
            rowData={rowData}
            columnDefs={columnDefs}>
        </AgGridReact>
    </div>
);
};

export default App;
```

Expected in the below table format

```
Make       Toyota      Ford      Porsche
Model      Celica      Mondeo    Boxster
price      35000       32000     72000
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a hacky solution but in my opinion, there is no built-in way to transpose data in `react-ag-grid`. So you can try to transpose data using custom function.

For example:

```
const transposeData = (data, columns) => {
  const colNames = columns.map((col) => col.field);
  const transposed = colNames.map((colName) => {
    const obj = { name: colName };
    data.forEach((row, index) => {
      obj[index] = row[colName];
    });
    return obj;
  });
  return transposed;
};

const App = () => {
  /* define rowData and columnDefs */

  const transposedData = transposeData(rowData, columnDefs);
  const transposedColumns = [
    { field: "name" },
    ...rowData.map((row, index) => ({ field: index.toString() }))
  ];

  return (
    <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: 400, width: 600 }}>
      <AgGridReact
        rowData={transposedData}
        columnDefs={transposedColumns}
        defaultColDef={{ width: 150 }}
        headerHeight={0}
      ></AgGridReact>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

You can see the whole example here: [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-fire-tzrqdt?file=/src/App.js)